# How to get crash log of android emulator crash in linux to popup or where to find full log?

Tags: android, linux, crash, android-emulator

Running ubuntu 22.04.1 with android emulator version 31.3.13.0

Yesterday when my emulator crashed a window popped up similar to this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxgAb.jpg

But today that window no longer pops up when the emulator crashes.  I am starting the emulator from the terminal and there is some crash stuff in the terminal but not to the level that was in that window, I tried adding -verbose but that just logged bootup stuff.  How do I get that popup crash window back or how do I get the full emulator crash log?